# Uber API: request_ride with sandbox_mode=True is throwing error message

Tags: python, uber-api

`request_ride` with `sandbox_mode=True` is throwing error message. Below is my code and entire error message.

```
#Python 3.x
from uber_rides.session import Session
from uber_rides.client import UberRidesClient
session = Session(server_token="something-special")
client = UberRidesClient(session,sandbox_mode=True)
#UberX product id
product_id = '04a497f5-380d-47f2-bf1b-ad4cfdcb51f2' 
response = client.request_ride(product_id, 37.77, -122.41, 37.79, -122.41)
ride_details = response.json
ride_id = ride_details.get('request_id')
response = client.update_sandbox_ride(ride_id, 'accepted')
print(response)

#error message
...
...
uber_rides.errors.ClientError: The request contains bad syntax or   
cannot be filled due to a fault from the client sending the request.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting a 4XX ClientError because you are attempting to request a ride with a server token. If you handle the error and inspect it, you'll see that it is a `401: Unauthorized error`.

In order to request a ride, you will need to obtain a OAuth2 Access Token with the `request` scope.

Server tokens have access to endpoints like Products, Time Estimates, and Price Estimates. To access more protected resources like a User Activity or Request endpoints, you will need to follow OAuth2 to [get an access token](https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication).

There is also an [OAuth2 Authorization example](https://github.com/uber/rides-python-sdk/blob/master/example/authorization_code_grant.py) in Uber's Python SDK.